# ¿Como cambiar el nombre(usuario que se muestra a la izquierda) que se muestra en la terminal de linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Quiero cambiar el usuario que se muestra en la terminal de linux.
Intente con este comando

```
sudo usermod -c "Nuevo-Nombre-Usuario" nombredeusuario
```

Pero no lo realiza, siempre me sigue mostrando el mismo usuario en la terminal.

Comment: No se puede cambiar cuando el usuario tiene procesos abiertos, funciona correctamente como dice la respuesta de @IvanBotero, puedes usar root para hacer el cambio y despues logearte nuevamente con el nuevo nombre de usuario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Comando

```
sudo usermod -l NuevoNombre AntiguoNombre
```

---

### Explicacion

Como lo indica la documentacion de [usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod):

```
-l, --login NEW_LOGIN
    The name of the user will be changed from LOGIN to NEW_LOGIN. Nothing else is changed. In particular, the user's home directory name should probably be changed manually to reflect the new login name.
```

Cuya traduccion seria:

```
-l, --login NEW_LOGIN
     El nombre del usuario se cambiará de LOGIN a NEW_LOGIN. Nada más cambia. En particular, el nombre del directorio de inicio del usuario probablemente debería cambiarse manualmente para reflejar el nuevo nombre de inicio de sesión.
```

> **Nota:** Bien puedes usar `sudo`, o tambien puedes iniciar sesion como *root* y ejecutar el comando desde alli. Aunque es muy recomendable iniciar sesion como *root*, ya que existen procesos que se ejecutan por parte de tu usuario a lo cual tu terminal mostrara un error.

[image: Error]

---

### Ejemplo Real

> ***Contexto:*** Tengo actualmente un usuario llamado **usuario**, voy a realizar el cambio de nombre, ahora se llamara **debian**, para ello, iniciare sesion como `root` y luego solo basta ejecutar el comando previamente explicado.

[image: Cambio de nombre]

---

#### Nota para Ubuntu

Para el caso que uses Ubuntu, recomendaria que hicieras lo siguiente:

**1)** Ingresa a tu terminal como root:

```
sudo -i
```

**2)** Cambia la clave de `root`:

```
passwd
```

**3)** Cierra sesion en Ubuntu.
**4)** Ingresa a una terminal virtual, ejecutando la combinacion:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>

**5)** Inicia sesion como `root`.

**6)** Ejecuta el comando:

```
usermod -l NuevoNombre AntiguoNombre
```

**7)** Vuelve a tu sesion grafica:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd>

**8)** Inicia sesion.

Comment: Escribo lo siguiente pero me da error de autenticacionuni_mie@ubuntu:~$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
uni_mie@ubuntu:~$ 
No se porque la clave es root

Comment: Si estas en ubuntu, puedes iniciar sesion como root, escribiendo `sudo -i`

Comment: @lucho He agregado una actualizacion al respecto de como se puede hacer en ubuntu

Comment: cambian las claves al cambiar el nombre de usuario? porque cambie el nombre de usuario a 1 y no me deja entrar

Comment: No cambian las claves

Comment: Lo que si ocurre es que debes iniciar sesion usando tu nuevo nombre de usuario

Comment: El nombre de usuario anterior ya no se usara para el inicio de sesión

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el usuario souser en las opciones de login pero en la terminal si me lo cambio a souser1 y algo que noto es que la clave cuando pongo sudo -i no me reconoce la clave anterior de souser1 que era souser

Comment: Considero que deberias reiniciar el equipo, ya que el manager de login puede requerir un reinicio para reconocer el nuevo nombre de usuario

Comment: Me muestra esto 
souser1 is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Comment: Basta que hagas esto adduser <username> sudo  desde tu usuario root

Comment: Ya que al cambiar el nombre de usuario, seguro lo ha excluido del grupo sudo

Comment: adduser <username> sudo  esto equivale a editar etc/sudoers y colocar souser1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL?

Comment: Exacto, consiste en agregar tu usuario al sudoers

Comment: Estoy intentando cambiar el nombre de otro usuario pero me muestra usermod: user uni_mie is currently logged in .Hice estoroot@ubuntu:~# sudo usermod -l souser uni_mie
usermod: user uni_mie is currently logged in

Comment: El error te lo indica el mismo sistema, no puedes cambiar el nombre de usuario estando este "logueado" en el sistema, debes hacerlo desde root

Answer (score 2):

Si sólo quieres cambiar el nombre que se visualiza en consola, basta con que cambies el valor de `PS1` en `~/.bashrc`

```
[eduen@EDUENPC ~]$ cat ~/.bashrc
#
# ~/.bashrc
#
alias subl="subl3"
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

- \u = nombre usuario
- \h = nombre del pc
- \W = ruta actual

En tu caso concreto

```
PS1='[Nuevo-Nombre-Usuario@\h \W]\$ '
```

Guarda cambios y listo.

También puedes cambiar directamente el valor en consola

```
[eduen@EDUENPC Escritorio]$ PS1='[Prueba@\h \W]$'
[Prueba@EDUENPC Escritorio]$
```

Comment: ¿Pueden existir dos propietarios de una carpeta. Un ejemplo el propietario de usr es root, pero como hago para darles permisos a un usuario no root sobre la carpeta del fylesystem, tendria que hacer formar a mi usuario parte del grupo de root?